# Composition of a unique arrow with the inverse of another

Tags: category-theory

Suppose we have the arrows $u:T \rightarrow Q$, $v:T \rightarrow P$ and $f:P \rightarrow Q$.  Furthermore, suppose $u$ is unique and $f$ is iso.

I understand that we can say that $v = u;f^{-1}$, but do we have enough information that $v$ is also unique?

I believe that $v$ is unique, but I'm not sure why.  I think it is because - by  the uniqueness of inverses - $f^{-1}$ is unique, and that when it is composed with another unique arrow ($u$), then the composition $u;f^{-1}$ must also be unique.

Can anyone confirm whether this is the case, please?

Answer (score 1):

Consider another $v^\prime \colon T \to P$, not necessarily equal to $v$. Then $v^\prime ; f = u$, since ex hypothesi $u \colon T \to Q$ is unique. Finally, composing with $f^{-1}$ confirms $v' = v = u; f^{-1}$.

Bonus remark: in higher categories, there is a natural notion of merely *isomorphic* morphisms, so we could potentially show a weaker result: that $v$ is unique *up to isomorphism*. In standard categories though, morphisms are either equal or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is true. Once you have two arrows (the same thing as two uni ue arrows) you can compose them (composition being a function).